# Can i use Angular UI Router in my project?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

we are starting new project which uses angularjs as UI script.

I've gone through angular ui-router for https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

UI-router module really great when compare to ngroute.

But I am afraid about the warning mentioned the ui-router's website homepage.

(Note: UI-Router is under active development. As such, while this library is well-tested, the API may change. Consider using it in production applications only if you're comfortable following a changelog and updating your usage accordingly.)

But i want to use this framework with angular.

Can anyone please suggest, will this cause any performance issue in future, much api will change, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the current version of angular-ui/ui-router works fine for you that is all you need.

> will this cause any performance issue in future

why should it? since you are going to save your copy of the current version of angular-ui and it runs on client side you will never have problems (if you update angular-ui in 5 years of course you are going to have problems, if you never update it will ALWAYS work)

the note you quoted means that the current support of that library might change, so all you have to do(if they don't provide support for older versions) is to save a copy of those docs.

Comment: I'm not sure about the javascript variable management of this ui-router and how they are destroying the scope.Thats why I was afraid.
Could you suggest on this doubt...

Comment: even if they destroy it, it will dont matter for you, as I stated download the current version of ui router and add a copy to your project, dont do <script src="http// some url that updates the file"></script> because that version will change, download your own copy and reference your code to it